# Copy file from a directory based on CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv, file-copying

I have some issues now concerning a code in PowerShell.

I want to write a script in PowerShell to copy files from one folder to another existing folder based on CSV file :

For example I have in my CSV two columns : one for the name of the file without the extension and one for the path where I want to copy my file into.

example of csv  :

```
File,Pathdestinationfile
test1_000,C:/Documents/test1
```

so I need to get my file from a path such as C:/Source and copy it to the specific destinationfile path mentionned in my CSV.

Here is the code that I have for the moment but it doesn't work :

```
Import-CSV C:\Users\T0242166\Documents\SCRIPT_CSV\testscript.csv | 
    Where-Object Name -Like $_.File | 
        foreach { Copy-item  -Path "C:/Source" -Destination $_.Filepathdestination -Recurse }
```

Can you please help me with this issue ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have provided comments in the script to help you understand what I am doing.

***(note: this can be condensed, but I separated it out so you can see it easier.)***

```
# Define your constant variable    
$sourceFolder = "C:\Source"


# Import Your CSV
$content = Import-Csv "C:\Users\T0242166\Documents\SCRIPT_CSV\testscript.csv"


# Iterate Through Your Objects From CSV
foreach ($item in $content)
{
    # Find the file you are looking for
    $foundFile = Get-Item -Path ($sourceFolder + "$($item.File).*")

    # Copy the file using the FullName property, which is actually the full path, to your destination defined in your csv file.
    Copy-Item $foundFile.FullName -Destination ($item.Pathdestinationfile)

}
```

**Condensed Version:**

```
# Import and Iterate Through Your Objects From CSV
foreach ($item in (Import-Csv "C:\Users\T0242166\Documents\SCRIPT_CSV\testscript.csv"))
{
    # Find the file you are looking for and copy it
    Copy-Item "C:\Source\$($item.File).*" -Destination $item.Pathdestinationfile
}
```

**Another Condensed Version:**

```
Import-Csv "C:\Users\T0242166\Documents\SCRIPT_CSV\testscript.csv" | foreach { Copy-Item "C:\Source\$($_.File).*" -Destination $_.Pathdestinationfile }
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete response. But still not working. It doesnt give me any error in the PowerShell command. Maybe there is a issue with my CSV ?

Comment: does your file name in the source folder have an extension? like .txt or .csv

Comment: If it does not, then that is why you are getting no results back

Comment: Just take out the `.*` after `$item.File` if there are no extensions

Answer (score 0):

Although you keep using forward slashes in the file paths, in PowerShell this would work:

```
# import the data from the CSV file and loop through each row
Import-CSV -Path 'C:\Users\T0242166\Documents\SCRIPT_CSV\testscript.csv' | ForEach-Object {
    # get a list of FileInfo objects based on the partial file name from the CSV
    # if you don't want it to find files in subfolders of "C:\Source", take off the -Recurse switch
    $files = Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Source" -Filter "$($_.File).*" -File -Recurse
    foreach ($file in $files) {
        $file | Copy-Item -Destination $_.Pathdestinationfile
    }
}
```